# Can I insert the assembly instruction 'int 3' to debug the init() function of a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Say I have a Linux kernel module, and I want to debug its init() function.

Does the following code work?

```
void init(...)
{
    __asm__("int 3");
    ...
}
```

Comment: What I mean is the initialization function of a module.

Comment: You would want to use `printk` calls. Calling `int 3` in the kernel sounds like a surefire way to cause a kernel panic or mess things up.